# Adding a calculated column to a Large List -- how much time it will take?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, performance, large-lists

I have this question because we have a Production deployment and we need to update some lists with about 1 million items stored on them

The calculated field formula is very simple :take 1 field and return it as a Number

Formula :

```
0 + [TextField]
```

Is there a way to measure how much time it will take the field to be added to the list ?

This is for SharePoint 2010 Enterprise on windows server 2008.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've no idea, but I imagine no one else will either.

As an on prem system, it will vary depending on the resources available in your farm setup and what other demands are on the servers also.

Comment: adding the Calculated will lock the site or ca it still be used ?